# Error to create new type Date

Tags: java, date, type-conversion

I'm using the following convention and in date I get that method is deprecated (there is line that delete the date)
there is saw this message Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by `DateFormat.parse(String s)`.

how should i use it in the following code?

```
else if (typeName.equals("String")) {
    return new SwitchInputType<String>(new String("String test"));
}
else if (typeName.equals("Date")) {
    return new SwitchInputType<Date>(new -Date-("13:20:00"));   
}
```

the problem is with the `(new Date("13:20:00"));`

when i try to replace it with

```
return new SwitchInputType<DateFormat>(new DateFormat("13:20:00"));
```

i got the following message :

> Cannot instantiate the type DateFormat

how should I handle it?

Comment: You should use [joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateFormat` is an abstract class so it cannot be instantiated. Instantiate a `SimpleDateFormat` instead or use the static methods in `DateFormat` like `getDateInstance()` or `getTimeInstance()`.